# UIBarButtonItem error after changing it from UIButton

Tags: swift

i got this problem that i got some example code and i tried to exchange two normal buttons with `UIBarButtonItems`.

Can anyone say whats the problem in my code, i didn't know that normal buttons and `UIBarButtonItems` are that different.

So i changed the sender in showPopup from `UIView` to `UIButton` but now theres another error (see in screenshot below)

[Screenshot of the error messages and the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhi1g.jpg)

Sorry for posting images of code but not the code. 
Heres the `shopPopup` func:

```
func showPopup(sender: UIButton, mode:String, text:String="", row:Int=0) {
if !(mode=="edit" || mode=="new") { return }

let popVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewPopup") as! NewPopupVC
popVC.mode = mode
popVC.currentText = text
popVC.currentRow = row
popVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

let popPC = popVC.popoverPresentationController!
popPC.sourceView = sender
popPC.sourceRect = sender.bounds
popPC.delegate = self
popPC.permittedArrowDirections = [.up, .down]

present(popVC, animated:true, completion: nil) 
}
```

heres the func `addButton`. Thats where the first error is.

```
@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    showPopup(sender: sender, mode: "new")
}
```

and heres the part where the 2nd error occures.

```
@objc func handleLongPress(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
if gesture.state != .began { return }

let pt = gesture.location(in: tableView)
if let path = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: pt),
   let row = (path as NSIndexPath?)?.row,
   let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: path)
{

  showPopup(sender: cell,
            mode: "edit",
            text: todoList[row],
            row: row)
}
}
```

Updated Screenshot of the last occuring error.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjbo2.jpg)

Comment: Please don't add images of code, paste the code instead. Also, bar button items are not views, but popover presentation controllers have an option to use a bar button item as the source.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it. Also i'm sorry for my bad english, i hope i could explain my problem i a propper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to do this

```
 func showPopup(sender: UIButton, mode: String, text:String = "", row:Int = 0)
```

Change `sender` from `UIView` to `UIButton`

Comment: Thank you for your help! After i changed the sender from UIView to UIButton, how do i replace the sender in addButton? And now there is another error, the picture is in the main post.

Comment: Try This `func showPopup(sender: AnyObject, mode: String, text:String = "", row:Int = 0)` change `sender` to `AnyObject`

Comment: Wow, this helped! Now both the `addButton` and the `cell` don't show any error message. But instead `popPC.sourceView = sender` is showing an error: "Cannot assign value of type 'AnyObject' to type 'UIView?'"

Comment: If you want to make an `UIView` clickable as `UIButton` then you've to set `Custom Class` as `UIControl` to the `UIView` in `Main.Storyboard`

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand. The problem isn't the `UIView`, it's the `popPC.sourceView = sender` line in `showPopup` and it has something to do with from where the Popup should be shown (i guess).
Or am i wrong?

Comment: Could you please Upload a ScreenShot?

Comment: And also what you actully want to do could you please explain it, i can't get what you said.

Comment: Screenshot is in the post!

Comment: I want to let the popup show up from the UIBarButtonItem instead of a normal UIButton.

Comment: If you want perform click on `UITableViewCell` then you've to call your `func showPopup()` into `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` of `UITableView`

Comment: I'm sorry maybe this is too high for me. Can you send me any Code examples so that i can see how you think it should be?